# How to convert a string to a type for a MongoDB query

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am in the process of writing a query plugin that handles pagination of a data-table structure and in order to keep the maintenance as minimalistic as possible I am passing the name of the model in the plugin and querying via the given model name.

The problem is that the Mongo driver requires the type of the collection that is being queried not the name as a string. I believe I have made good headway in getting the type using reflection however when passing the type in i get an error that the type (`t`) can not be accessed:

```
public ActionResult ListTablePartial(string modelName, int pageAmount)
    {
        Assembly[] assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
        foreach (Assembly assembly in assemblies)
        {
            IEnumerable<Type> types = from x in assembly.GetTypes() select x;
            foreach (var t in types)
            {
                if (t.Name == modelName)
                {
                    var data = _dataService.GetCollectionQueryModel<t>(
                        Query.And(
                            Query.EQ("IsActive", true),
                            Query.GTE("CreateDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)),
                            Query.LTE("CreateDate", DateTime.Now.AddHours(23))))
                        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the error is here: `_dataService.GetCollectionQueryModel<t>` `cannot resolve symbol t` but it is definitely a type, any ideas?

Comment: `t` is not a type, it is an object (of type System.Type), holding information about a type. You cannot use t as generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing here is that by taking `t` out of a collection of `Type` objects, it is in fact *not* a Type and is not valid to a generic method. The [`Type` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx) is an object representing the metadata of a type, not a Type recognizable to the compiler for use in generics. Since `t` is an instance of the `Type` class, it's therefore not recognized.

The only thing you can pass in to a generic method are other type parameters passed into the current scope (via class or method generic parameters) or compile-time constant types.

If you wish to use generics with an instance of `Type` you can do so, but it requires using some reflection rather than simple composition:

```
var data = _dataService
    .GetType()
    .GetMethod("GetCollectionQueryModel")
    .MakeGenericMethod(t)
    .Invoke(_dataService, new object[]
    {
        Query.And(
            Query.EQ("IsActive", true),
            Query.GTE("CreateDate", DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7)),
            Query.LTE("CreateDate", DateTime.Now.AddHours(23))))
        .OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate);
    });
```